# Queuing/saving retrofit requests and send them later when there is poor/no internet connection

Tags: android, retrofit, android-room

I have my android application which is not build to work offline, so it is reliant on network connection/data.

App makes a lot of network calls updating the api with new set of data.

I am making changes in it to make it work offline.

Approach I am thinking I will create a Room data base in which I will save the retrofit requests and when there is connection I will pull them from the data base and send it to the api.

does that sound right?
Is there any other better approach, where I can save requests when there is no connection and when there is connection send those saved requests to the server.

Also can we save requests in Room database

I am not intending on doing database synchronisation with BE(API) and BE(API) deals with requests.

your suggestions are valuable

Thanks
R

Comment: At first glance it doesn't sound right. But maybe it will do if you add some specific  examples - what kind of interaction with api your app should maintain. Let's imagine that in offline mode you've saved 10 equal requests to api and then - all of them will be shoot when connection is on? Without knowing your app's specific it seems that local db with local data and data synchronization with rest api is the first method to think about. P.S. Excuse me for my ignorance, but what is "BE" you've mentioned?

Comment: Hi @sergiytikhonov thank you for replying. sorry my fault by BE i mean BackEnd(API).
Yes you are right, lets say we have a User with properties name, age, and so n so. and 10 equal changes have been made, I will stack all those requests and post them all at once and API deals with them, which is correct.

Comment: If I want to save requests in Room database, how should i approach that

Answer (score 1):

At once I want to say - I think what you ask is not very good idea and I can't recommend do like that. But it's your choice. What came into my mind as for saving requests in Room (maybe is oddity, but let it be):

1. Let's assume you have N api endpoints. Each of them has some parameters (from 0 to M).
2. You can make a table **requests** in your Room, that contains (1 + P) columns, where P - maximal amount of your endpoints' parameters (maybe there should be date for chronology and a mark whether request was already processed as well). All columns have String type. First column - is for endpoints name (key). That key you will use to define with it one of your Retrofit endpoints.
3. In offline mode you save your request in table **requests**' row - name for endpoint and serialised to JSON string for each parameter.
4. When network is on - you query your table, deserialise your api parameters and in some loop recreate your rest Api requests in some huge when-statement like that:

   `// restApi - your Retrofit interface
    // apiName - endpoint String key from db
    // parameter1 - endpoint's parameter1, restored from db saved JSON string
    // ....
    // parameterM - endpoint's parameterM, restored from db saved JSON string
    when (apiName) {
      "endpoint1" -> restApi.someYourEndPoint1(parameter1)
      "endpoint2" -> restApi.someYourEndPoint2(parameter1,parameter2)
    ..........
    }`

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. when you say saving requests is madness, what would be the right approach now that you know what I am actually looking for. what would be your recommandation

Comment: Honestly I have no much details about your app's specific. Maybe you have some unbreakable limitations that make this approach the only decision (for example your BE on some purpose in no way can change its api for implementing some sort of sync). But maybe I should replace "madness" with "oddity" :)

Comment: hey, even if the BE supports sync, we still need to send those requests which happened on the device right? i am not sure if BE supports sync how will it make it easier? can you give an example please

Comment: Hi. For me app maintaining offline mode - is when your app keeps copy of server data locally. And local db - is kinda [single source of truth](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#truth), so you need to keep your local data relevant in some way (both when connection is on and off), so you have to implement sync process anyway.  Of course when connection became on after some pause you have to call your BE api (with WorkManager's help for example). Maybe in your case that api could be the same as in your current state, I don't know.

Comment: But for me the most clear choice here - is to save in db some marks, that some data was changed in offline mode and you want to sync it with server. In some cases there could be complicated logic, when this changed data could be changed as well by another user on another device and so on, then logic of sync should be corrected. But again, maybe you have some use case, where described implementation would be overarchitecturing    . If you describe more details in your post, maybe somebody could give you answer oriented specifically on your use-case, not an answer in general

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, it was very helpful.

Comment: I am intrigued with your use-case. If it will not bother you, post here your approach after implementing

Comment: sure I wil, thank you for following up on that. yes it is an interesting use case,

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps to create this request with MVVM and Room in retrofit :
First of all :
Create a table for saving offline data  and with Dao interface,you can create insert and Query functions such as below (the reason for using suspend is that it indicates the method can be used in coroutine scop for handling asynchronous operations):

```
interface DaoOffInfo {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertOffInfo(newsOffInfo: NewsOffInfo)

    @Query("SELECT*FROM newsoffinfo")
    fun getAllNews():LiveData<List<NewsOffInfo>>
}
```

the second step in ViewModel create an insert method to save data from retrofit:

```
fun getAllNews(category:String){
          CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
              var response =repositoryNews.getAllNews(category)

              withContext(Dispatchers.Main){



                  if(response.isSuccessful){


                      newslist.postValue(response.body()!!)
                          response.body()!!.articles
                    

                     for (i in response.body()!!.articles.indices){
                         name= response.body()!!.articles.get(i).title
                         desc = response.body()!!.articles.get(i).description
                          date = response.body()!!.articles.get(i).publishedAt
                         content = response.body()!!.articles.get(i).content

                         if(desc.isNullOrEmpty()){
                             desc = "There is no Description for this article."
                         }
                         if(content.isNullOrEmpty()){
                             content = "There is no Content for this article."
                         }



                      }

                       insertData(NewsOffInfo(0,name, desc.toString(),date,content.toString()))
                  }


                      }
                  }


          }
```

and val allNews =repositoryOffLine.allNewsInfo ,infact read the data from database then in activity or fragment for handling internet connection using `connectivityManager` and this methods :

```
  private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean { 
connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

            val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
        }
```

Finally here checking the internet is connected or not :

```
 private fun updateRecyclerViews(){

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

          //if internet is connected 
}
else {
      //no internet connection ,read the data from room and display which means that with allnews that created to read from database ,we can observe the values.

 

    viewModelRetrofit.allNews.observe()...

}
}
```